# If not exist create folder and copy files from network location

Tags: batch-file

I have Java files located on a shared Windows network location.

As example:

```
\\abc.local\sharedfiles\java
```

I have a working GPO, which runs a `.bat` file from the Startup scripts locattion and makes a directory if it does not already exist.

```
if not exist "C:\Java" mkdir C:\Java
```

Who can help with the code to copy the files from the network location to the client folder, `C:\Java`, only once.

Something like, `if not exist` > `create folder A` > `copy files from source X to folder A` - `if exist` > `stop process`.

Comment: `if exist "C:\Java" goto :eof`, followed by the code to copy.

Comment: You could also simply mkdir the folder no matter what.  If it is there already, it wont hurt anything.

Comment: [xcopy](https://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html) or [robocopy](https://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html).

Comment: Thank you all for the help in this. I created the following working script with your comment.
   
 if not exist "C:\Java" mkdir C:\Java
start \\inl.loc\sysvol\inl.loc\scripts\Java\javafilesv1201.bat
if not exist "c:\Java\javaverificatiev1201.txt" xcopy \\inl.loc\dfs\scratch\Java\jdk1201 c:\Java\jdk1201 /s